# What programming languages should I leanr if I want to make a social media app/website like facebook?

Tags: website

The title says it all. What programming languages will I need to learn to create a social media app/website like Facebook?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Facebook is written in PHP. I don't think that anybody would recommend creating a site in PHP these days. Facebook even needed to create their HHVM to improve performance and compensate for PHP's shortcomings.

In all honesty, there are a million ways you could go. Myself, I would recommend Spring Boot for the backend and React JS for the front end, but that is just an opinion.

So... Java and JavaScript. But you could just as easily write an effective app in Go, Ruby, or any other language. It's about how you utilize the language, the existing frameworks, and how much time you're willing to put into building libraries that may not exist for functionally you may need.

Comment: This isn't even on topic here!

Comment: Sorry Michael :( I would've put it on hold if I could... probably shouldn'tve answered!